# What is the cheapest/laziest way to touch up discolored hardwood?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood, stain, hardwood-refinishing

I rent, so the amount of money and labor I am looking to invest in my floors is small. That said, there are a number of spots where the hardwood has a sort of "dead" look that I wouldn't mind touching up if there is a straightforward way to improve the situation. The floors don't have to look new (clearly that is not going to happen), but maybe these spots can be less visible than they are now. Is there a relatively simple approach?

Related question: even the parts of the floor that aren't discolored are pretty beat up. Any recommended products for just improving the overall shine and appearance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Throw a rug over it. Anything more extensive, clear with your landlord, first.

Comment: "Refinish floor" and "cheap/lazy" are two concepts that don't belong together in the same novel.

Comment: The laziest? Add more stains and eventually, it all blends in.

Comment: Rugs aren't cheap! Also, I would have to scatter tiny rugs all over my apartment.

Comment: Seeing it is a rental, rug/floor covering are about all you should do by yourself.  Anything else probably need to talk to landlord.  Might reduced rent for work you put in(or not).

Answer (score 0):

Get a sanding block and sand those spots to see if you can remove those stains. Then get some Polyurethane, you'll have to match the sheen, and put on three or four coats.

Comment: Come on Jack, you can be lazier than that!

Comment: @DMoore  OK, I'll  go with the rug like Ecnerwal  suggested. :-)

Comment: No, this is definitely meets my standard for laziness. If you told me I had to sand the entire floor down, that would be another story. Basically I'm looking for the "drywall compound" equivalent...

Comment: I would agree with poly on the top if you can match but the bottom looks more like danish oil.

Comment: I would suggest that attempting to match the stain and finish is anything _but_ a "lazy" job. Trying to do even a _slightly_ reasonable job of matching is going to take a lot of samples to get the colors and the top coat correct. Not even _remotely_ lazy in my book!

Comment: @FreeMan Come on now.. I just said to try and match the sheen, not the stain. There are different types of wood there so matching the stain would be tough... just get the sheen close.

Comment: Fair enough. Still probably more than one should do when renting without permission _in writing_ from the landlord. ;)